# Is learning all this necessary?

Tags: bootstrapping

Is it even worth it to learn all of this Bootstrapping and stuff that just feels like I'm not really doing any work?

I feel like it's a bit cheat-y, y'know?

I showed someone a site I had built and they said it was good, but it didn't work well at all across multiple platforms.

So, I Googled for some tips on how I can make the site adjust to different screen sizes, and every link I went to just listed different Bootstrapping things and plug-ins that'll do it for me.

I want to learn this stuff for myself so I have better control over it, I suppose.

Is that really a good idea, or would it be more worth it to look into Bootstrapping and junk?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*What types of questions should I avoid asking?*](/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I would advocate to learn how things work first, and then use libraries/frameworks to accelerate your workflow.

The idea behind this is that if those tools have bugs, or issues, you'll have a much better capacity to dig in and debug.

Trying to build all of these tools yourself, however, is NOT recommended (*unless its for exploratory reasons*). These libraries and frameworks exist for a reason, they have many contributors (*something you can't compete against as a solo dev*) and they solve real-world problems.

That being said, learning how to properly select a given lib/framework for a given use-case is a skill really worth building. And that comes from understanding what problems the libs/frameworks solve, which is the result of having explored "the inner workings" by digging in.

In the end, these tools will greatly accelerate your development speed, which is great, especially when it's business related (*your job*).

Comment: That makes sense, actually, thank you for responding.